# Jasmine Test in Angular for controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-controller

I get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`
The problem is that the common is module and a factory and the problem is on my line

```
var ctrl = $controllerConstructor("resetPasswordSentScreen", { $scope: scope, common: common});
```

Here is the full test:

```
describe('resetPasswordSentScreen', function () {

    var scope, $controllerConstructor;


    beforeEach(module('common', 'app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controllerConstructor = $controller;
    }));

    it('it should navigate to the correct url when backToLogin is called ', function (common) {
        var ctrl = $controllerConstructor("resetPasswordSentScreen", { $scope: scope, common: common });
        var mocklocation = sinon.stub({ url: function () {}});
        expect(scope.backToLogin()).toBe(mocklocation.url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you set up a js fiddle for this?

Comment: Hi Michael and thank you for you quick response. http://jsfiddle.net/mariac/KvY5z/

Comment: Looks like $controller doesn't get injected. My approche is always like this:

    $NAME$ = $injector.get('$controller')("$NAME$", { $scope: $scope });

Comment: Thank you all for the your observation. I still have a problem. But this time i think is my references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the problem, the problem is that you can't inject stuff into your functions like you do  in your code. To inject you need to call `inject` as you did in the `beforeEach`. So, if you want to inject that factory, you need this:

```
it("message", inject(function(common) {
 ...
}));
```

There is how you inject. That should work.

Comment: Thank you @Jesus Rodriguez. I fix the problem but still have issue with my references

Comment: The code you show is correct, the only problem was the inject. Are you sure your error is on that line? I built an example with more or less your idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/uW4VMNJUqqZitCPLwkoS?p=preview

Comment: Hi Jesus my error now after adding in my it () the inject is the following :Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cvAuthProvider <- cvAuth. And i have declare the common as : angular.module('common').factory('cvAuth', ['$http', '$cookieStore', cvAuth]);

Comment: Do you have all dependencies in your TestRunning-Framework (e.g. Karma) configured?

Comment: Hi @Malmi i fix the issues with my dependancies. Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/mariac/KvY5z/1/ Now i have the following error that i am trying to solve TypeError: Cannot call method 'path' of undefined.

Comment: You're doing a `location = location` You're assigning a variable to itself :P. Inject it and then assign it.