# TypeError: $scope is undefined in Angular controller unit test with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine

This is a *very* simple, quite pared down test and controller.  My controller 'LedgerCtl' has an injected service 'LedgerService' that I test elsewhere, so in my LedgerControllerSpec I created a function that stands-in for the mocked service.  When I execute the test, I get the 'scope undefined' error.  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928231/angularjs-unit-test-scope-undefined) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701764/jasmine-test-in-angular-for-controller) are the closest answers I found; however neither solve my issue.

```
angular.module("TeamSportApp", [])
.controller('LedgerCtl', function($scope, LedgerService) {
    $scope.ledger = [];
    // init controller by getting list of pics
    $scope.getLedger = function() {
        $scope.ledger = LedgerService.getLedger();
    };
    // init list
    $scope.getLedger();
})
```

and the spec

```
var ledgerStaticData = [
{ "ID": 1, "Name": "Item1", Balance: 2100 },
{ "ID": 2, "Name": "Item2", Balance: 3300 },
{ "ID": 3, "Name": "Item3", Balance: 2000 },
{ "ID": 4, "Name": "Item4", Balance: 1500 }
];



describe('controllers', function(){
var ctrl, mockLedgerService, $scope;

beforeEach(module('TestApp',[]));
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {

    mockLedgerService = {
        getLedger: function() {}
    };

    spyOn(mockLedgerService, 'getLedger').andReturn(ledgerStaticData);
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('LedgerCtl', {$scope: $scope , LedgerService: mockLedgerService });
}));

it('Should call mockLedgerService getLedger', function() {
    expect($scope.ledger.length).toBe(4);   <<<--- SCOPE UNDEFINED HERE
});
});
```

Comment: Looks like maybe mockLedgerService.getLedger() is returning correct data, but that data is not being set on $scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test doesn't load the module where the controller is defined (`TeamSportApp`). Add the following line:

```
beforeEach(module('TeamSportApp'));
```

Also, defining the following empty module is unnecessary:

```
beforeEach(module('TestApp',[]));
```